# How to throw an error back to jQuery from an MVC HttpPost. (With customErrors turned on)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my JS I have:

```
$.post("/Controller/MyAction", { myData: data })
.done(function (data) {

})
.fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

In my controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyAction(MyTest data)
{
    var response = DoSomething(data);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw (new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase));
    }
}
```

However I have customErrors turned on in my web.config.  It appears to be intercepting the throw and instead of getting a 401 message back I getting a 500 message.

How can I throw an error back to jQuery from an MVC HttpPost (With customErrors turned on)?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the StatusCode in the Response.

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyAction(MyTest data)
{
    var response = DoSomething(data);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }
}
```

This will go to the `$.post` method's `fail` handler.

Comment: I set the status code to 401 and it does not go to the fail handler.  It is going to the done handler.